# Adding a new row that depends on a rows data at select command?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

My assignment is:
I have a table called Results(codeCompetition, Contestant, place). I need to make a select that shows: Contestant, nr_points where nr_points = 10 if the place of the contestant, for that competition was 1, nr_points = 8 for 2nd place and nr_points = 5 for 3rd place.

```
go
create view Loc1 as
select Rezultate.sportiv, sum(10) as puncte from Rezultate
where loc_ocupat = '1'
group by sportiv
go

go
create view Loc2 as
select Rezultate.sportiv, sum(8) as puncte from Rezultate
where loc_ocupat = '2'
group by sportiv
go

go
create view Loc3 as
select Rezultate.sportiv, sum(5) as puncte from Rezultate
where loc_ocupat = '3'
group by sportiv
go

-- create view
go
create view total_result as
select * from Loc1 union select * from Loc2 union select * from Loc3
go

-- sum of all the points from every competition that a contestant participated
select total_result.sportiv, SUM(total_result.puncte) as total_puncte from total_result
group by total_result.sportiv
```

Now this code works ok, but I'm not sure it is the easiest answer. Is there any kind of condition with multiple choices in T-SQL ? (without creating a new table, column)

I'm looking for something like:

```
if(place == 1)    
  add(10_points)
if(place == 2)
  add(8_points)
..............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement and use the following one sql query:

```
select sportiv, 
SUM( CASE WHEN loc_ocupat = '1' THEN 10
          WHEN loc_ocupat = '2' THEN 8
          WHEN loc_ocupat = '3' THEN 5
     END
) as total_puncte 
from Rezultate
group by sportiv
```